# Create User Prompt to Last Entire SAS Project

Tags: sas, prompt

I'm using SAS Enterprise Guide 5.1 and I have a project made of 4 import statements and 4 sas programs.  The SAS programs are connecting to Teradata and deleting tables, create and loading tables, creating indexes (in Teradata), granting roles, and finally, collecting statistics.

My question is this.

How can I have a user (using Enterprise Guide) start running this project, interactively providing their user name and password one time so that they do not have to store that information in each of the four sas scripts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a prompt to one of your programs. You can elect, during the prompt creation, to allow the prompt value (macro variable) to be available during the entire project.

[Creating Reusable Programs by Using SAS® Enterprise Guide® Prompt Manager](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings11/309-2011.pdf)

**UPDATE:**
In most cases the prompt NAME is the macro variable (&name)...however, some prompt types (other than TEXT) create more than 1 macro variable (a DATERANGE creates 8). You can view the name(s) of macro variables that will be created from your prompt inside the PROMPT MANAGER (View/Prompt Manager). Select a prompt, then right-click on it and choose "Show Macro Variables..." and any and all macro variables will be displayed...just don't forget to preface the prompt names with an & in your code.

Comment: Thanks.  This is exactly what I needed.  Just as a note to anyone else looking for this information.  In your code you reference the varaible as &variable.  Remember to use the "." after the variable name.  it doesn't appear that it is always needed, but the failure to provide it caused my code to error out.

Comment: Updated my answer regarding seeing the macro variables created from a prompt.